# Finding the index of several identical words

Tags: javascript, latex

I have a laTeX string like this

```js
let result = "\\frac{x}{2}+\\frac{3}{x}";
```

I want to find the index of "frac"s in the string and put them in a array then I want to find the first '}' char after "frac" and replace it with "}/" and finally remove "frac" from the string.

I used this block of code but it just work correctly when we have one "frac"

```js
let result = "\\frac{x}{2}+\\frac{3}{x}";

if (result.indexOf("frac") != -1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < result.split("frac").length; i++) {

    let j = result.indexOf("frac");
    let permission = true;
    while (permission) {

      if (result[j] == "}") {
        result = result.replace(result[j], "}/")
        permission = false;

      }
      j++;

    }
    result = result.replace('frac', '');
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

**OUTPUT:** `\\{x}//{2}+\\{3}{x}`

Could anyone help me to improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

`frac(.+?)}`

is the literal frac followed by a capture group that will capture one or more of anything `.+` until a `}` and replace it with that anything plus a `}/`

Using the function replacement to grab index and replace

```js
let result = "\\frac{x}{2}+\\frac{3}{x}";
let pos = [];
const newRes = result.replace(/frac(.+?)}/g,function(match, found, offset,string) {
  console.log(match,found,offset,string)
  pos.push(offset)
  return `${found}/`; // return the found string with the added slash
})
console.log(pos)
console.log(newRes)
```

Older answer using two sets of code

```js
let result = "\\frac{x}{2}+\\frac{3}{x}";

let re = /frac/gi, res, pos = [];
while ((res = re.exec(result))) {
   pos.push(res.index);
}
const newRes = result.replace(/frac(.+?)}/g,"$1}/")
console.log(pos)
console.log(newRes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration. You resolved half. It should be ''\\{x}/{2}+\\{3}/{x}''. a '/' char must be between the values in the {}. and could you explain me what is ''frac(.+?)'' !?

Comment: See update with explanation

Comment: PS: I just wrapped the statement in the while in another set of brackets to create a better truthy statement

Comment: AND I just remembered that a function replacement get the offset so we can have just one process - see update

Comment: and ONE more question: how can I use it when I have nested "}" like this:
"\\frac{x}{2}+\\frac{sqrt{9}}{x}"
Is it possible!?

Comment: What is the expected output of the "nested" version?